# How to disable popup when turning on/off Wifi in Tasker

Tags: 9.0-pie, tasker, 8.1-oreo

I have Tasker on 2 phones. One is Huawei, Android version 9 while the other is KTouch, Android Version 8.1. Both have the same settings provided (Battery optimization disabled, Usage access enabled etc). However, Tasker in Huawei was purchased from the App Store but Ktouch is an .apk version downloaded from the Huawei phone. KTouch do not allow Play Store to be installed :(

What I want is to switch on the phone at a set time and turn on wifi. For the turning on of Wifi, I used the Net > Wifi "On" feature.

For Huawei, Wifi automatically turned on without any popup. However for the KTouch, there was a popup asking user to deny or allow for Wifi to be turned on. May I know how to disable this popup and just auto turned on the Wifi, just like Huawei's?